# Возможно ли из Spring Model "напрямую" отобразить jpeg(BLOB)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Имеется аннотированный для Hibernate класс "Teacher". Фото в MySQL базе хранится в **LONGBLOB**.

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher", catalog = "school")
public class Teacher {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "teacherId", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int t_id;

    @Column(name = "teacherName", nullable = false)
    private String t_name;

    @Column(name = "photo")
    private byte[] image;
}
```

Его DAO :

```
//Добавить учителя

public void addTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(teacher);
    }

//Получить список учителей
public List<Teacher> listTeachers() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Teacher> listTeachers = session.createQuery("FROM Teacher").list();
        return listTeachers;
    }
```

Его сервис :

```
@Transactional
public void addTeacher(Teacher teacher){
        this.teacherDao.addTeacher(teacher);
}
@Transactional
public List<Teacher> listTeachers() {
        return this.teacherDao.listTeachers();
}
```

И контроллер :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "teachers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listTeachers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("teacher", new Teacher());
        model.addAttribute("listTeachers", this.teacherService.listTeachers());
        return "teachers";
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/teachers/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTeacher(@ModelAttribute("teacher") Teacher teacher) {
       if (teacher.getT_id() == 0) { 
           this.teacherService.addTeacher(teacher);
       }else {
           this.teacherService.updateTeacher(teacher);
       }
       return "redirect:/teachers";
```

Возможно ли получить на ".jsp" странице изображение из Teacher наподобие этому?

```
<th>${teacher.photo}</th>
```

Возможно, что я изначально написал не верный код? Спасибо!

Comment: Прежде, чем разбираться с JSP и байтовым представлением изображения, ознакомьтесь с базовыми принципами отображения изображений в браузере. <th>${teacher.photo}</th> - этот код не имеет никакого отношения к HTML-у, отображающему изображение. Нет тега IMG. У тега IMG должен быть атрибут SRC. И вот там уже могут быть варианты, но немного, например, этот: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413075/1341148. Оффтоп - кто-нибудь донесёт до преподавателей весть о том, что технология JSP устарела 10 лет назад? Только на русском SO до сих пор задают вопросы по JSP, и сразу видно что студенты...

Comment: @bobzer , да, спасибо, с Base64 - тоже вариант.
Если кому то нужно, то есть еще вариант [Upload & display from/to Database](https://sites.google.com/site/adrienitnotes/java/web-apps---spring-mvc-hibernate/spring-form-regular-fields-image-upload-display-from-to-database-hibernate-one-to-one-mapping)